# Accessing grailsApplication from spock unit test testing code in src/groovy

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I'm trying to test some code that's in src/groovy using Spock. The code I'm testing references grailsApplication. Since it's in src/groovy, I used dependency injection to inject grailsApplication into the bean, like so:

```
ticketRequestEmailInfo(TicketRequestEmailInfo) {
    grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
}
```

The problem I'm having is when the test code hits the line of code that references grailsApplication, I'm getting a NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'config' on null object
```

My test class has the following:

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class TicketRequestEmailInfoSpec extends Specification {
    def setup() {
        grailsApplication.config.acme.purchase.trsUrlBase = "http://localhost:8082/purchase/order/"
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `Holders.grailsApplication.config`:

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class TicketRequestEmailInfoSpec extends Specification {
    def setup() {
        Holders.grailsApplication.config.acme.purchase.trsUrlBase = "http://localhost:8082/purchase/order/"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't works injecting `grailsApplication` to test as `def grailsApplication` ?

Also you can import it as `import static grails.util.Holders.config as grailsConfig`.

And then use it as

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class TicketRequestEmailInfoSpec extends Specification {
    def setup() {
        grailsConfig.acme.purchase.trsUrlBase = "http://localhost:8082/purchase/order/"
}
```

Comment: Using def grailsApplication in the test gives the NullPointerException. Must be because the code I'm testing is in src/groovy. Using Holders.grailsApplication.config as suggested above works though.